# Reshaping big data long based on column name patterns

Tags: r, data.table, bigdata, reshape

I have a (large, in reality) dataset with street blocks; it has house numbers for the beginning ("from", in the variables below) and end ("to") of the block, for both the right and left side. Here's an example:

```
library(data.table)

# raw address file
raw <- data.table(id = letters[1:4],
                  rfrom = c(1, 101, 201, 301),
                  rto = c(99, 199, 299, 399),
                  lfrom = c(2, 102, 202, 302),
                  lto = c(100, 200, 300, 400),
                  street = c('birch st',
                             'main st',
                             'birch st',
                             'elm rd'),
                  rlat = c(1, 11, 21, 31),
                  llat = c(2, 12, 22, 32))
# for illustration only, hence the nonsensical coordinates
```

I want to reshape this long so that I have one observation for the left and right side of each block. I intended to use `melt` from `data.table` for this, which does give correct results:

```
long <- melt(raw,
             id.vars = c('id', 'street'),
             measure.vars = patterns('from', 'to', 'lat'),
             value.name = c('from', 'to', 'lat'))

# this produces the dataset I want:
long
   id   street variable from  to lat
1:  a birch st        1    1  99   1
2:  b  main st        1  101 199  11
3:  c birch st        1  201 299  21
4:  d   elm rd        1  301 399  31
5:  a birch st        2    2 100   2
6:  b  main st        2  102 200  12
7:  c birch st        2  202 300  22
8:  d   elm rd        2  302 400  32
```

However I realized that it's melting based on column position, not the contents of the column name (i.e. I want it to look at the "r" or "l" prefix in the name), because if, for example, you list one "left side" variable before the equivalent right one while keeping all other variables right before left, it returns incorrect results:

```
# now switch the order of the latitude variables:
raw <- data.table(id = letters[1:4],
                  rfrom = c(1, 101, 201, 301),
                  rto = c(99, 199, 299, 399),
                  lfrom = c(2, 102, 202, 302),
                  lto = c(100, 200, 300, 400),
                  street = c('birch st',
                             'main st',
                             'birch st',
                             'elm rd'),
                  llat = c(2, 12, 22, 32),
                  rlat = c(1, 11, 21, 31))

# melt then gives us incorrect results:
long <- melt(raw,
             id.vars = c('id', 'street'),
             measure.vars = patterns('from', 'to', 'lat'),
             value.name = c('from', 'to', 'lat'))
# latitudes are associated with the wrong observation now:
long
   id   street variable from  to lat
1:  a birch st        1    1  99   2
2:  b  main st        1  101 199  12
3:  c birch st        1  201 299  22
4:  d   elm rd        1  301 399  32
5:  a birch st        2    2 100   1
6:  b  main st        2  102 200  11
7:  c birch st        2  202 300  21
8:  d   elm rd        2  302 400  31

# in a related, but less important issue, I'd prefer the variable column list l or r not 1 or 2
```

Obviously reordering columns is an option, but I'd prefer to avoid it, mainly because it strikes me as tenuous to rely on that as the program changes over time, other people make edits in it, etc, particularly given how difficult it is to check that the results are correct after the melting. (And in an ideal world I'd have a variable in the long dataset with the l/r prefix.)

It seems like this is a [known issue](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/1739), but--and I'm guessing I'm misunderstanding something--my attempts to use [the workaround](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/pull/4731) of the new `measure` function aren't working (I just get an error that R can't find a function called measure).

At this point I think my best option is to switch to using `pivot_longer` from `tidyr`, but I thought I'd ask if someone could point out what, if anything, I'm doing wrong or let me know if there's a better/more efficient way.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: If by transform you mean reorder, I should have clarified that I have a strong preference not to reshape by column position, both because it feels risky to rely on position, but also because there are many variables I'm looking to melt so it would be a hassle. If there's really no better option I'll consider it, but I'm hoping to avoid it.

Comment: You rather use `pivot_longer` it will not have this issues. Just run your code. and it does give incorrect results

Comment: The problem is that the real data is quite large, and, as far as I understand, `pivot_longer` isn't nearly as efficient as `melt`

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you have identified the problem correctly: the side of the street data ("left" or "right") is encoded in the column names. This is similar to the flower part ("petal" and "sepal") embedded in the iris data column names. Because of the nature of the problem, `melt` alone can't do the job.

Transforming such data frames and isolating the data in the column names is a pivoting operation as you suggest. I have found the approach developed in the cdata package to be quite transparent. However, the transformation is not based on patterns...instead it uses a carefully designed and unambiguous control table to manage the transformation.

To illustrate, I start with your second `raw` data table.

```
raw <- data.table(id = letters[1:4],
                  rfrom = c(1, 101, 201, 301),
                  rto = c(99, 199, 299, 399),
                  lfrom = c(2, 102, 202, 302),
                  lto = c(100, 200, 300, 400),
                  street = c('birch st',
                             'main st',
                             'birch st',
                             'elm rd'),
                  llat = c(2, 12, 22, 32),
                  rlat = c(1, 11, 21, 31))
```

Build a control table with a new key column indicating the `side` of the street and the value columns `from`, `to`, and `lat`.

```
control_table <- wrapr::build_frame(
    "side" ,  "from",  "to",  "lat" |
    "right", "rfrom", "rto", "rlat" |
    "left" , "lfrom", "lto", "llat" )
setDT(control_table)
```

If you don't want to use the wrapr package, you can build the control table as a conventional data table.

```
side <- c("right", "left")
from <- c("rfrom", "lfrom")
to   <- c("rto"  , "lto")
lat  <- c("rlat" , "llat")
control_table <- data.table(side, from, to, lat)
```

In either case, the control table has the same structure.

```
control_table[]
#>     side  from  to  lat
#> 1: right rfrom rto rlat
#> 2:  left lfrom lto llat
```

The second step is to operate on `raw` using `rowrecs_to_blocks()` from the cdata package, where the `id` and `street` columns are identified as values to repeat as many times as necessary to complete the transformation from row-record (wide) form to block-record (long) form.

```
DT <- cdata::rowrecs_to_blocks(
  wideTable     = raw, 
  controlTable  = control_table,
  columnsToCopy = c("id", "street")
)
setDT(DT)
```

If I understand your question correctly, then I think this produces the form you want regardless of the column order you start with. Note that the side of the street data is now an explicit "coordinate" that helps identify records.

```
DT[]
#>    id   street  side from  to lat
#> 1:  a birch st right    1  99   1
#> 2:  a birch st  left    2 100   2
#> 3:  b  main st right  101 199  11
#> 4:  b  main st  left  102 200  12
#> 5:  c birch st right  201 299  21
#> 6:  c birch st  left  202 300  22
#> 7:  d   elm rd right  301 399  31
#> 8:  d   elm rd  left  302 400  32
```

Of course other packages can produce similar results. I happen to like the consistency of the cdata transformation.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Is `rowrecs_to_blocks()` faster than `pivot_longer`? I'm not seeing much in the `cdata` documentation about speed/big data, but I may have missed it

Comment: I haven't run across any speed information. (If I get some time, that would be worth doing.) One of the things I like about the cdata approach though is illustrated by the `side` column that stores the right or left side of the street (something you mentioned you would have in an ideal world). It makes the data fully "coordinatized" so that the data can be reshaped into any convenient form.